# Why keep git history clean?

Tags: git

I had a talk with teammate about git. I tried to convince him that he should use amend, rebase -i and use meaningful commit messages. He just asked "why" and well... That's a good question. I tried to use argument like *clean history, easier to read and find bugs, and well it looks nice*. He just said that who the hell reads git commits or check out tree, everybody just commit — push and when time comes merge it. Why bother?

To be honest I had no idea what to say. The worst part is that rest of the team thinks similar. Can somebody please help me, how can I convince them to do a little more work just to keep git clean?

The worst part is I am new in the team and a lot younger than others, so I can't just use *more experienced developer* card.

**EDIT**

Since there is a misunderstanding about what I meant by *rebase*:
I try to convince team to use rebase -i when you are working on local changes, on local branch which is not pushed. Just to clean up if you didn't amend in time.

Comment: Having `git rebase` as part of the workflow when you are in a team is a very bad idea. You are changing history continuously, with disaster waiting to happen. Rather have a clear branching policy or use squash commits.

Comment: @Bernhard That depends. I use `git rebase` all the time ... in my own repositories, before commits are pushed to the team repo.

Comment: I check commit history a lot. How did this code become the way it is now? Who introduced what change? I also use `git bisect` to find bugs, so logical commit units are very helpful.

Comment: @Bernhard it wasn't specified how `rebase` is used so... but you make a good point tho

Comment: @mnestorov Well, I would encourage everyone to push their commits at least daily. If you have only one copy of your code in a local repository, it is a disaster waiting to happen at some point.

Comment: I (like any other developer) have a "remote" repository on a server that I push to, but it's still mine. I can rebase my feature branches there all I want. As long as no one else bases their work on my work-in-progress branches, there's no problem.

Comment: @Bernhard yes I agree with that. But I wouldn't consider rebasing as part of a workflow a bad thing, if it is used to - squash (as you mentioned) or re-order on a need-to-do basis :) (or anything that has a logical explanation)

Comment: Without meaningful commit messages, it would be hard to filter commits, debug, generate statistics, etc. Rebase or merge is a controversial issue. In our team, we use `git pull -r` or `git rebase` to update the same branch before a push, and use `git pull` or `git merge` to introduce a different branch. And for personal/experimental branches, it's allowed to do whatever as needed.

Comment: You shouldn't use _more experienced developer_ card, even if that's true.

Comment: "who the hell reads git commits" people who have to maintain the code and merge pull requests, etc. AKA probably this team. That's code repositories 101.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question boils down to whether you need a history in your VCS repositories or not. You do need it in cases when:

- You need to find the task in your tracker. The task may contain information about why the change was introduced.
- Need to read commit message that explains the change
- Find the person who introduced the change in order to ask him questions about it. Maybe break couple of fingers.
- Figure out when the bug was introduced. Often that's just curiosity, but it may uncover interesting trends.
- Revert the change if malfunction was discovered late
- Catch up with the changes made by your colleagues yesterday. Or while you were on vacation.

So if the history is easy to inspect, these goals are easily achievable.

Answer (score 3):

When you do not read git commits, keep a clean history, and maintain your project properly, you screw yourself FORWARD in time. A time WILL come, where you will need to go back, check something and you will not be able to do that. Then hell will break loose. Your code will be hell to maintain, bugs will come up and will be dismissed as not important, nobody will care about quality. Your job becomes annoying, and if you treat your job like that, then wy bother? That's a pathology you do not want to get into.

What your team is doing is a sign of *not caring*. The *why bother* and *who cares* arguments are not qualities (again.... **usually**) that build good software.

On any project, in all of the teams I have worked at, there are use cases for us, when we need to maintain old version and checkout old releases. Sure, you DON'T DO it regularly, but a time will come when you will need to do something in the past and you WILL need gits help for that. That time always comes. If people decide that it doesn't matter and that they won't maintain such a product, then they do not care about their job or the work they do (**usually**... **usually** that's the case)

This is one of those cases where you have to shoot yourself in the leg a couple of times with git before you start paying attention - lose a few projects, get yell at because you jeopardize company code, lose WEEKS of progress, etc. etc.

I've met with teams and even companies that treat git like a nuisance and don't even try to keep any workflow. These teams, *usually*, have bad codebases, where it's utter hell to maintain anything.

It's hard to change senior peoples minds on these things, their ideology has gotten them too tight to consider anything else. Nevertheless, you keep your git clean, you follow good git practices, you follow good workflows. You DO NOT jeopardize your ability to create clean git history, that will make your life easier, for the sake that someone, even a Senior, will tell you otherwise.

Comment: Your whole answer is about using git in general. It doesn't explain why rebasing would be beneficial over branching/merging. All those things you still can

Comment: Because the question is no about rebase specifically, but about having a clean git history

Comment: Ok, fair point. Maybe OP should convince his team to start writing clear commit messages first.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays Git is not used in a vacuum, and I think your team is right.

There is often a bug tracker, a code review tool (that uses pull requests) and a CI system that build the code and runs the tests in cloud. These are integrated together and systems are in place to ensure that no broken code is merged to the main branch and everything is properly reviewed and approved before the merge.

And primarily these tools are used to keep track of the work and not the Git history.

If there is a bug, then VSCode's Git Lens extension shows immediately who changed the problematic line the last time. So we can ask him. But even if we are not sure we can always go to the team chat and mention "hey why did we wrote this that way?". We don't assign blame.

In the last 5 years since we moved to Git from Perforce I never had to look back or bisect the git history ever.

Answer (score 0):

What is engineer?

The answer is: a person who can solve some problems.

You see, we are the problem solvers. So please don't try to be perfect.

Is `git commit` with very beautiful and meaningful message great? Yes, it sounds great but does it solve any problem - the **real** problem, instead of the problem that your suppose. If it doesn't, why would you spend your time on that?

The value of a very good thing without solving any problem is 0. Why? Because we are engineers, we just solve problems. That's it.

I'm sorry but if I were your teammate, I would not agree with you either. The only reason that I would spend my time to make some meaningful commit message is that I get an issue, which caused by a meaningless commit message. Is there such a case? I don't think so...

In the real world, as @Calmarius said, we rarely read the historical commit messages because we have so many ways to debug or trace some historical changes. For example we can clearly see all of commits in Gerrit. If I want to check what was committed by someone, I would search in Gerrit, that's quite simple, fast and much clearer than commit message.

So remember: you are a problem solver, you are not some perfect-product maker because your resource and your energy are always limit. If your team has less and less things to do, you may have much time to do some other things, such as make some beautiful and meaningful commit messages. But if this really happens, I think you should consider getting another offer because that might be a sign of "game over" of your company...

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 questions here:

- Are meaningful commit messages useful?
- Is rebasing better than branching?

### Meaningful commit messages

This is useful, because you will notice bugs/regressions in the future. Then it helps you guess what change could have caused these bugs in situations where it is difficult to debug them.

### Rebasing over Branch/Merge

I prefer the branch/merge workflow over rebasing:

It still gives you a clean history for your master branch, while not deleting information, which might be useful when tracking down a specific bug/regression.
It is better to have lots of concise commits, because it helps you find specific changes in the code quickly without having to go through a huge commit.

Of course, you do want to amend code sometimes, like when you missed something for that commit. The commit description should give you a hint whether this might be the case.